# Custom Profile Center - CloudpagesURL returns error 500 (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I am implementing a Custom Profile center.
I tried to follow the method suggested by Adam here:
[Custom Profile/subscription center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171911/custom-profile-subscription-center)
But get a 500 error when trying to load the page,

So, I further narrowed it down to the Cloudpagesurl Ampascript function example here:

https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/

And still get the error.

The Landing page contains only the following code, from the example in the documentation:

```
%%[

var @firstName
set @firstName = Lookup("Members", "First Name", "Subscriber Key", _subscriberKey)

]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Hello %%=v(@firstName)=%%,</h2>
      <p>Welcome to your personalized landing page.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**PS**

The SFMC instance is new, MC Connect works as expected, and I have 3 email subscribers.

Comment: You're missing the opening "%%[" at the beginning of your AMPScript

Comment: As Macca said, you are missing the opening `%%[`. You could also add some basic exception handling to still be able to display the CloudPage even if the data is missing: 


`%%[
set @firstName = Lookup("Members", "First Name", "Subscriber Key", _subscriberKey)

IF empty (@firstName) THEN
  SET @firstName = "Customer" 
ENDIF

]%%`

Comment: You can also use an email to troubleshoot your ampscript. Simply hard code any requestparameter() values

Comment: @Macca  thank you for jumping in on this.

unfortunately I am missing it in the question only, not on the page - corrected the question.
The issue is still unresoloved.
Any idea?

Comment: @zuzannamj, thanks for your help.
the %%[  was missing on the question only.
What do you mean "the data is missing" how can subscriber key be missing from someone who got the email?

Comment: I meant if the first name is missing, not the sub key. Have you tried using the if/else I provided in my comment?

Comment: @EazyE, Could you elaborate?
How do I do that?
Would be interesting to know.

In this specific case, this is a two-row ampscript and the first row is var \\@firstName... so the error is in the second, or in the executing environment.

Comment: @zuzannamj, I tried it, yes. 
This doesn't seem to be the issue.
When the string is empty, the page still renders. Using the same original code - if I just cut the row which begins with "set" - the page renders without any assignment to the variable - showing an empty string. So the problem is in this row - how can I be sure Members exist? It's either the table Members doesn't exist, or the column First Name doesn't exist in Members. Where do I see Members?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply that Members (as appeared in the code from the documentation mentioned in the question) is **not** a Data Extension.

I thought Members was some kind of a Master Data Extension which holds all members.
It's not.

Solution:
Create 'Members', populate it. The code works.

Hopefully this saves someone time in the future. 
(Please Vote this answer up if it does).